# How to set UINavigationController as root from UITabBarController.?

Tags: swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I am working on App where Login is shown to user, after successful login user is landed on dashboard. where 4 tabs are shown to navigate to respective use.
I have to use, `UITabBarController` for four tabs from dashboard and `UINavigationController` for navigation from LoginView.

I set my UITabBarController to navigationController, when user successfully logged in.
Each view will have one logout button, on click of which I have to set my `navigationcontroller` back to root.

Here is code sample which I have done.

1. My UITabBarController

   class TabBarVC: UITabBarController {

   ```
   let dashboardViewObj = DashboardVC()
   let registerViewObj = RegisterVC()
   let alertViewObj = AlertVC()
   let historyViewObj = HistoryVC()
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       self.viewControllers = [dashboardViewObj, registerViewObj,historyViewObj,alertViewObj]
       // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

       dashboardViewObj.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: .search, tag: 0)
       registerViewObj.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: .history, tag: 0)
       historyViewObj.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: .contacts, tag: 0)
       alertViewObj.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: .bookmarks, tag: 0)
   }
   ```
2. In my LoginViewContoller

let tabbarObj = TabBarVC()

```
@IBAction func loginBtnClicked(_ sender: Any) {        
            self.navigationController?.setViewControllers([tabbarObj], animated: true)
        }
```

Now on click of logout button from any of these views, I need to set navigationController as root.
How to do it...?

Following chart will help to understand what I need.
Any help will be appeciated.

[image]

Comment: If each ViewController has its own logout button, the button's action could probably be: `self.tabBarController?.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)`. Though ideally you would use a separate object (class) handling the user's login status, to which other ViewControllers could react to.

Comment: @KishanBhatiya :- tried that too already. but not working. not navigating back to rootview

Comment: @frzi :- Tired this after you send this, but didn't work
both ways I try, but no crash, no issue and not expected output.
Not navigating back to root view

Comment: oh, I realize when you click the login button you do `setViewControllers([tabbarObj])`. This will make the TabBarController the only ViewController in the NavigationController stack. You may want to push the TabBarController instead `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(tabbarObj, animated: true)` :)

Comment: @frzi :- Thanks for correcting, its working as expected.
Can you pls just add this comment to answer so that I will accept it and upvote it, and will be useful to others too...

Answer (score 2):

@frzi :- Thank you very much for answers and correction from comment section.

I just did what you suggested.
The following line is corrected in my LoginViewController.

```
self.navigationController?.setViewControllers([tabbarObj], animated: true)
```

To updated line as

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(tabbarObj, animated: true)
```

And on Logout button action just added the line,

```
self.tabBarController?.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

and it worked...
Cheers J...

Answer (score 1):

You can use unwind segue easily instead of setting the root view controller or pop view controller or even dismiss methods!
See  [this for full description](https://matteomanferdini.com/unwind-segue/)

Answer (score 1):

When you are login all you need to put this code in your logout button action and it will redirect you to login page.

```
   var window: UIWindow?
   let appDelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

      let VC = self.appDelegate.storyboard1.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Your controller name") as! loginViewController
            self.appDelegate.navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: VC)
            self.appDelegate.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
            self.appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = self.appDelegate.navigationController
            self.appDelegate.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

it will work.